# Isabelle: Evaluating formula with Quantifiers

Tags: isabelle

Why does the following work:

```
fun f :: "nat ⇒ bool" where
  "f _ = (True ∨ (∀x. x))"
```

But this fails

```
fun g :: "nat ⇒ bool" where
  "g _ = (True ∨ (∀a. True))"
```

with

```
Additional type variable(s) in specification of "g_graph": 'a 
Specification depends on extra type variables: "'a"
The error(s) above occurred in "test.g_sumC_def"
The error(s) above occurred in definition "g_sumC_def":
  "g_sumC ≡ λx. THE_default undefined (g_graph TYPE('a) x)"
```

Similarly, the following succeeds,

```
value "True ∨ (∀x. x)"
```

but this fails

```
value "True ∨ (∀x. True)"
```

with

```
Wellsortedness error:
Type 'a not of sort enum
Cannot derive subsort relation {} < enum
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer is:** In your first function definition type inference easily infers that `x` is of type `bool`, while in your second definition, the bound variable `a` is not used anywhere else and thus its type is arbitrary (`'a`). Which is what *Additional type variable(s) in specification ...* expresses.

If you constrain the type of `a` explicitly, e.g.,

```
fun g :: "nat ⇒ bool" where
  "g _ = (True ∨ (∀a::bool. True))"
```

the function definition is accepted.

**A longer answer:** Since the definition of `g` is not recursive you could turn it into using `definition` instead of `fun`. Then your first attempt does not fail completely but the result might surprise you. After

```
definition g :: "nat ⇒ bool" where
  "g _ = (True ∨ (∀a. True))"
```

the type of `g` is `'a itself => nat => bool` instead of the intended `nat => bool`. The reason is the same as for the failure of `fun` before. Since `a` is of arbitrary type, this additional type has to be recorded in the type of `g`, which is done by introducing an additional dummy argument which just states this additional type explicitly. Here `'a itself` is a type whose constructor `TYPE(...)` -- taking a *type* as argument -- allows us to encode type information on the term level. E.g.,

```
TYPE('a)   :: 'a itself
TYPE(bool) :: bool itself
TYPE(nat)  :: nat itself
```

Then `g TYPE(nat)` is the version of `g` where `a` is fixed to be of type `nat`.

Concerning your `value` statements, the reason for the second one to fail is not really related to the above. In the first statement the universal quantifier binds a variable of type `bool` whose values can be enumerated explicitly and thus a result can be *computed* by considering all those values. In contrast, in your second statement the bound variable `x` is of an arbitrary type `'a` whose values cannot be enumerated explicitly.

Comment: I would like to add that recording the type of x in the function definition is absolutely necessary as well, i.e. this is not some technicality that one could get rid of somehow: imagine the function had not been ´∀x.x` but, for instance, `f _ = (∀x y. x=y)`. This function would evaluate to `true` for `'a = unit`, but to false for pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 1):

The following fails:

```
fun f where "f _ = (∀a. True)"
```

because the type of `a` has *hidden polymorphism* (i.e., there is a type variable inside your function's body that is not present in the function's type signature), which upsets the function package's internal proofs.

If you explicitly give `a` a type as so:

```
fun f where "f _ = (∀a::bool. True)"
```

or is you give `a` a type that is also in the function's type signature, as so:

```
fun f where "f _ = (∀a::bool. True)"
```

the function definition succeeds. Your example:

```
fun f where "f _ = (∀x. x)"
```

succeeds, because `x` is forced to be type `bool`.

As for your `value` commands, Isabelle attempts to generate executable code for your expression, and hence needs to not only know the type of your for-all statements, but also be able to *enumerate* all possible values of it, so that it can test them all. Types such as `bool` work fine, but type variables like `'a` or infinite types such as `nat` are not enumerable, and hence Isabelle cannot generate code for them.